# Lowercase in \citet{}, uppercase in \citep{}

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, capitalization

My institute's format standards require that author's name in `\citet{}` citations should appear with first letter in uppercase, whereas in `\citep{}`, all letter should be in uppercase.

For example: `\citet{Wooldridge2002}` should give `Wooldridge(2002)` whereas `\citep{Wooldridge2002}` should give `(WOOLDRIDGE, 2002)`.

How can I accomplish that? I tried a naive solution with `\MakeUppercase`, but it didn't worked. See example (`\bibitem` extracted from `.bbl` generated from `.bib` with our style):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
  I want the first letter of author's name in uppercase here: \citet{Wooldridge2002} (ok).

  I want all letters of author's name in uppercase here: \MakeUppercase\expandafter{\citep{Wooldridge2002}} (not ok).

  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
  \bibitem[Wooldridge(2002)WOOLDRIDGE]{Wooldridge2002} WOOLDRIDGE, M.~J\@.
  \textbf{An Introduction to Multiagent Systems}. Chichester: John Wiley \&
  Sons, 2002.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I rephrased the paragraphs in the code to reflect better my intentions.

Comment: I think it would take much effort to do this... Why don't simply use `\textsc{\citep{Wooldridge2002}}` to get it in small caps?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This is another case where an `ac` (all caps) font shape would come *very* handy.

Comment: Your solution worked, @karlkoeller! Very simple and functional. However, I'm using @MBR's answer as a solution because it redefines `\citep` so that I don't need to add `\textsc{...}` in all occurrences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citep
   {\begingroup\NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
         \@ifstar{\scshape\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\scshape\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
\makeatother
```

It simply redefines the `\citep` command, with extra `\scshape` to get the name of the authors in uppercase.

Comment: But is small caps what the OP('s institute) requires?  I understood it to be all caps.

Comment: This worked! A little "caveat", however, is that the first letter is slightly bigger than the rest. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately it is not easy to get all caps. I tried different things (using the TeX command `\uppercase` as well as the LaTeX macro `\MakeUppercase`) but couldn't find a way to have it easily in all caps. Problem is that small caps are defined directly by the font (so you can easily switch from normal to small caps font), whereas if you want all caps it is not just a "font flavor" to choose, you have to translate the catcode of each letter in lowercase in uppercase (if I undersand well the behaviour of `\uppercase`). If I find a way I'll let you know!

Comment: Would it be easier to make `\citet{}` lowercase (except for first letter)? I mean, if the bibitem is like: `\bibitem[WOOLDRIDGE(2002)WOOLDRIDGE]`, then `\citep` would use the uppercased name, so we would need to change `\citet` to lowercase it, right?

Comment: To switch from upper to lowercase is as problematic as to switch from lower to uppercase, for the same reason, as far as I understand. [David Carlisle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) could probably give you more insightful details about all that!