# Natbib: Capital letters in "\citep" except for lowercase "et al."

Tags: citing, natbib

I changed the font shape of command `\citep{}` so that all letters appear in small-caps, according to following redefinition given in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131827/lowercase-in-citet-uppercase-in-citep):

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citep
  {\begingroup\NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
     \@ifstar{\scshape\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\scshape\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
\makeatother
```

However, when the authors' names are in the abbreviated form, the "et al." appears in small-caps as well. But, I want "et al." to remain in lowercase. Is this possible? I am using the `dcu` bibliography style.

Comment: For example, the stardard dcu style is **(Smith et al., 2017)** with the modification I got **(SMITH ET AL., 2017)**.  But, I want **(SMITH et al., 2017)**.

Comment: It won't work unless you change the style (the bst) so that the et al is in some command that one could change.

Comment: No problem. I already created a _mydccu style_. Because I need a specific punctuation between the authors' names.

Comment: So you already have your own version of `dcu.bst`?

Comment: Yes, but I only changed the names in the list of references. It's an easy change to make. My question is more complex for me.

Comment: @Lara Can you create a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/117534) -- one that we can copy-paste and compile on our own systems to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Open your already-modified version of the file `dcu.bst` in a text editor.
- In that file, change all five [5] instances of

  ```
  et~al.
  ```

  to

  ```
  \textnormal{et~al.}
  ```

  (`\textup{et~al.}` works too.)
- Save the modified bst file.
- Rerun BibTeX, and then LaTeX twice more.

Incidentally, do note that this approach to rendering the authors' names in small-caps in citation call-outs has several significant drawbacks. First, it does not ensure that the connector word "and" will be typeset with lowercase letters; this case arises when bib entries have exactly two authors. To remedy this, insert the instruction `\providecommand\harvardand{\textnormal{and}}` after loading `natbib`. Second, this approach also does nothing for cases of "et al." and "and" generated by `\citet`, `\citet*`. Third, it doesn't render the authors' names in small-caps when using `\citeauthor`, `\citealp`, `\citealt`, and so on. Last but not least, the formatted bibliographic entries will continue to have the authors' names shown in regular (i.e., non-smallcap) letters -- quite likely creating a weird discrepancy between the ways the authors' names are typeset in the citation call-outs on the one hand and in the bibliography on the other. A full solution, then, would involve modifying the `dcu.bst` bibliography style file much more thoroughly.

---

A full MWE and associated screenshot:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{ab,author="Aaa and Bbb", title="Thoughts", year=3001}
@misc{abc,author="Aaa and Bbb and Ccc", title="Thoughts", year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citep
  {\begingroup\NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
   \@ifstar{\scshape\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}%
           {\scshape\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{dcu-mod}
\providecommand\harvardand{\textnormal{and}}

\begin{document}
\citep{abc}, \citep{ab}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```