# citep Upercase and cite downcase for apalike bst

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite, bst

I need to format the citations on text to rounded (it's ok) and (not ok):

- on `\cite`, titlecase
- on `\citep`, uppercase

For example:

- `bla bla~\cite{author}, bla bla` needs to print:

  > bla bla Author et. al. (2020), bla bla
- `bla bla~\citep, bla bla` needs to print:

  > bla bla (AUTHOR et. al., 2020), bla bla

I'm using [this](https://github.com/piccoli/PP-LaTeX) LaTeX styles (`cls` and `bst` in apalike).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a minimal working example (MWE) for your current setup.

Comment: Your name and location information in your proile lead me to suspect this might be ABNT style (which is a bit special I think). In that case I suggest you abandon `apalike` for either [`abntex2cite`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite.pdf) of https://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2 or https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt.

Comment: @moewe you was correct! I'm brazilian and maybe abntex2cite it's a good choice, but, the version I use it was derived from this and modified by some people to a Post-Graduate Program. Because of this, I was intend to change his.
@epR8GaYuh in the link I posted, there are bst , cls and tex files used to compile the text. I don't now how can post here more details, can you help me? 
Thank`s !!!!

Comment: If you want to stick to `apalike` that might be a bit more tricky. A solution will quite likely involve redefining highly internal macros. You have a much better chance of getting answer if you can post a short example document (along with an example `.bib` entry) instead if pointing to an off-site resource (ideally you would create an example that does not need all the customised files from your template). (Such an example document is often called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)

Comment: @moewe I tried to use the suggestion posted on this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131827/lowercase-in-citet-uppercase-in-citep it seems work, but changed the style of citation... and I still try to create a MWE and post here early as possible...